# Cannot mount NFS volume with Docker, can mount it otherwise

Tags: docker, nfs, freenas

I'm trying to set up an NFS volume shared by a TrueNAS server to use with my Docker container using Docker compose:

```yml
volumes:
  data:
    name: data
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: nfs
      o: addr=[some_ip],rw,nfsvers=4
      device: ":/Share/volumes/data/"
```

However, when creating the stack (`docker-compose up -d`) Docker throws an error:

```
ERROR: for web Cannot create container for service web: failed to copy file info for /var/lib/docker/volumes/data/_data: failed to chown /var/lib/docker/volumes/data/_data: lchown /var/lib/docker/volumes/data/_data: operation not permitted
```

Now, I can mount this share and access it outside of Docker - and I can run the container if I add the `:nocopy` flag at the end of my volume statement:

```yml
    volumes:
      - data:/some/dir #:nocopy
```

...but then data does not seem to be stored on the NFS share at all.

I've read suggestions online to use the `no_root_squash` flag, but it seems to be both insecure and not easily available with the TrueNAS system.

I'd really appreciate some pointers in solving this.

Thanks!